# Meteor Users: add user by admin user only

Tags: meteor

I'm using the [useraccounts](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts) package in my Meteor app. I want an admin to be able to add a new user (and disable signing up through the frontend). Therefore, I have added a Collection with a SimpleSchema as per the suggestion of [meteor-collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#attach-a-schema-to-meteorusers). I'm alos using AutoForm to create an 'Add user' page.

```
<template name="addCustomerProfile">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Edit document</h1>
    {{#if isReady 'updateCustomerProfile'}}
       {{#autoForm collection="Users" id="userForm" type="insert" }}
        <fieldset>
          {{> afQuickField name='emails.0.address'}}
          {{> afQuickField name='emails.0.verified'}}
          {{> afQuickField name='services.password'}}
          {{> afQuickField name='username'}}
          {{> afQuickField name='profile.firstName'}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add User</button>
      {{/autoForm}}
    {{else}}
      Nothing
    {{/if}}
   </div>
</template>
```

I can add users whenever the 'services.password' is not added to the form, but obviously no default password is set for the user in the Mongo database in that case. How can I add a field so the admin can set a default password for that user (which the user will then be able to change later on).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `forbidClientAccountCreation` and `sendEnrollmentEmail`?

```
Accounts.config({
  forbidClientAccountCreation: true
});

Meteor.methods({
  'inviteUser': function (doc) {
    check(doc, YourForm);
    let userId = Accounts.createUser(doc);
    Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail(userId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Good suggestion, will certainly try. But where would you call the inviteUser from. I mean: is it sufficient to display the autoform and bind the 'inviteUser' to the submit button?

Comment: I got it partially working. I see in the console that the link is http://localhost:3000/#/enroll-account/:token is sent. So I added "AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('enrollAccount');". When I then go to the URL via my browser I always get the sign in page. I can log in using the email address (for enrollment) with the default password and get successfully logged in. But in reality I was thinking that I would get a page where I could fill in the token?